# prove that there exists one continous function $g$ with $g(x) = x+ \frac{1}{2} \cdot \sin(g(x))$

Tags: functions, continuity, fixed-point-theorems

I am supposed to use Banach's fix-point-theorem to prove that there exists exactly one continous function $g:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $g(x) = x+ \frac{1}{2} \cdot \sin(g(x))$ for every $x \in [0,1]$.

The first thing I need to do is verify that I am allowed to use Banachs's theorem. Hence I need to show that $\text{Im}(g) \subseteq [0,1]$
However, I am not able to do that. I know that for every $x$ we have: $-1 \leq \sin(x) \leq 1$.
Therefore $$ x+ \frac{1}{2} \cdot \sin(g(x)) \leq 1 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 = \frac{3}{2}$$
which is obviously more than $1$. Also:
$$ x+ \frac{1}{2} \cdot \sin(g(x)) \geq 0 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot (-1) = -\frac{1}{2}$$
I also tried finding $g$ but failed.
Any hints on this?

Comment: You try to apply the fixpoint theorem to the wrong space. I.e., nowhere do yo need to itereate $g$ to find that some $g(g(...(g(x_0)...))$converges to a point $x_1$ such that $x_1=g(x_1)$. Instead, you want to find $g$ such that $g=T(g)$ for a suitable $T$ (and find it by iterating $T$)

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. So basically I have to find a function T with the fixpoint g or at least show that a contraction mapping T with fixpoint g exists. However, could you elaborate a bit on how one can find this specific T?

Comment: @2GR8 The $T$ in this case would be $T(f) = \left(x \mapsto x + \frac{1}{2}\sin(f(x))\right)$, which is a map from $C[0, 1]$ to $C[0, 1]$.